# How to restrict access user access to swf file on server?

Tags: apache, flash

if there is a vulnerable swf player file on server, ex. site.com/player/player.swf how do I restrict user access to that file. I still want to use it as player on my site , but don't want to allow attacker to access that file directly through url.Server is Apache on Linux.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible. This is because the user's browser internally acceses the URL as if you typed it in your address bar. Answers based on referer are incorrect (referer can be easily spoofed). You should fix the security leak instead.

Comment: I thought it would be like that , well there goes my money for player update. BTW thanks for answering.